# ServiceMix and Camel : How do I create routes?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

This part of the puzzle is my nightmare, I have deployed ServiceMix, and 2 Java apps on 2 different tomcat instances :

First app :

```
http://localhost:8080/textmsgClient
```

Second app :

```
http://localhost:8181/textmsgServer
```

Now my two apps need to communicate, though I want that communication to go through ServiceMix, so I can do some logs and everything.

I've created a blueprint XML file in the `./deploy` directory, but what routes should I put in them?

I can't do this :

```
  <route>
    <from uri="http://localhost:8080/textmsgClient"/>
    <log message="Test log"/>
    <to uri="http://localhost:8181/textmsgServer"/>
  </route>
```

so what is the correct thing to do ?

by the way, my XML file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
      <route>
        <from uri="file:camel/input"/>
        <log message="Moving ${file:name} to the output directory"/>
        <to uri="file:camel/output"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the list of [Camel Components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html).  Not knowing what type of data you are sending between services, it is difficult to recommend which one to use.  However, theres a component for pretty much every data type you can imagine, and even support to make your own!

**Edit**
An example might be:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:textmsgClient"/>
    <log message="Test log"/>
    <to uri="direct:textmsgServer"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for responding, I'd like a simple HTTP redirection using Camel, but between these two distinct apps. Also what URL should I configure in the first app so it can communicate through ServiceMix and Camel.

Comment: What do you mean a http redirection?  Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achive and what sort of message will be communicated between the services?

Comment: My first app communicates directly with my second app right now. I want to put Camel in between them. So I tell my first app to communicate with Camel first (at a specific URI), and Camel forwards that to the second app. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Try not to think of it as forwarding - one route puts a messages in an endpoint, another route picks up messages from an endpoint.  So you need a route in your first app which takes messages from a source and puts them somewhere (again, take a look at the list of components, direct is useful).  Then in the second app, pick up messages from that same endpoint, and do something with it (maybe take a look at the bean component?).  Not knowing how you are using your app, what type of messages you are sending, how you are sending them or what you are doing with them, I cant be of much more help.